# returning validation fail like response in none validation scenario

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

so lets say i have 2 functions , i send a ajax request to `init` function  and init function calls `check` function

```
function init(Request $request){
    $this->check($request);
}

function check(Request $request){
    $request->validate(['something' => 'required']);
}
```

in this scenario if validation fails laravel returns a response to ajax call with `Status Code: 422`  , and i dont need to return any response

now if i want to check something else and if that fails i want to response just like validation fail response

```
function cehck(Request $request){
    
    if($somethign_else_failes)
    {
        return response()->json(['errors' => ['email' => ['The email is invalid.']]], 422);
    }
}
```

but this wont return back the ajax call response ... it will just return it to `init` function
and i need to add another return in the `init` function

basically i dont want to have multiple returns in nested functions , if it failes at any level i want to return the ajax response at that level

i would like

```
function init(Request $Request){
   $this->cehck();
   // do the rest of code
}

function check(){

     if($something_wrong)
         //abort with reponse message 
}
```

instead of something like this

```
function init(Request $Request){
   
   $response = $this->cehck();
   
   if( $response == failed )
   {
      //abort with reponse message 
   }
   
   // do the rest of code
}

function check(){

     if($something_wrong)
         return failed flag   ; 
     
}
```

Comment: then you would need to throw an exception ... this is how call stacks work, you need to return things from them as you are unwinding the stack or you can throw an exception which bubbles up through them ... why would you not want to be returning a value from `init`? what if this stuff doesn't fail, are you not returning any response at all from your action?

Comment: @lagbox then i have to check the response of child function in the parent/caller function ... to see if i have to abort or carry on with the rest of code  .... i want to avoid extra `if` in my code and abort the operation in the child function

Comment: then your only option is to throw an Exception

Comment: `return $this->check(...)`

Comment: @nice_dev i would need to check the response if child function in the parent function to see if i have to abort or let the rest of the code to execute ... i want to avoid the extra `if` in the parent function ... i've added additional info to my question

Comment: @lagbox thanx throwing an exception worked

Comment: You can also simply return what is returned from the child function.

Comment: @nice_dev the thing is the code has to go on in the parent function  if the child function doesn't return a failed falg ... so should return child response  only if it has failed

Comment: Although this is opinion based, I would have returned appropriate success or failure messages from the child function itself.

Comment: @nice_dev depends on the scenario , i have to call this check function from multiple functions for different operations .... i might have done it if it was called just once

Comment: Well, it's opinion based. If I were to make it, I would have made all callees follow a single behavior. Throwing an exception is also a good idea like you did, but with a try-catch in the callee to rollback if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer

```
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

throw ValidationException::withMessages(['somefield' => 'something is wrong with this field ']);
```